# Migrating Data from Production to Developer Sandbox

Tags: data

I have a requirement from a client for a migration of data between prod and dev sandbox. 
My Customer does not have a full copy sandbox. Is there any way apart from the data-loader we could use to migrate only limited records from production to dev sandbox?

Comment: Use a partial sandbox with an appropriate template. Most orgs have access to at least 1 partial sandbox I believe. If you must go with a dev sandbox then you will need to use a data migration tool

Comment: Thanks Eric.  My initial idea was to go with sf to sf integration . But unfortunately it doesn't go well between prod and sandbox .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service https://www.import2.com/salesforce to achieve that. And if you don't need full sandbox, you can use the free trial version to create a sandbox with a subset of data.

disclaimer: I am part of import2

Answer (score 0):

Another vendor solution is [Gearset](https://gearset.com/), with their  Data Deploy feature. The overall product is quite useful and reasonably priced with an easy learning curve (and I'm not an employee of Gearset or have any financial stake in the company)